# Ethernet / Network errors

Tags: ethernet

I have problems downloading files over ethernet on Linux. There are no tx or rx errors and the network speed itself is as expected.

But apt update and apt upgrade shows lots of checksum mismatches, and downloads from maven repos result in ssl errors. Also the occasional web page fails to load.

Connecting to the same network using wifi works fine, and so does connecting the same computer to another ethernet network.

Would tx/rx errors show up if the problem is between two switches down the line?

Is it possible to measure ethernet cable quality in Linux?

Comment: wifi works fine  .....  Replace / upgrade the Ethernet Driver;  try a new (pre-manufactured) cable.

Comment: Can't you plug a [frame sniffer](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to see if there are retries. Afaik apt uses protocols over TCP, that is integrity is checked.

Comment: @John I doubt that there is a problem with the driver, as it works on another ethernet network. I actually managed to get hold of a very long ethernet cable, so I am just about to replace all cables involved, one by one.

Comment: @mins any tips on how to filter on retries in wireshark?

Comment: Retries show up in Comm View (packet sniffer) but do not say why (probably do not know why) the retransmission took place.  Replacing cables is probably the best strategy.

Comment: That's a long time I didn't do network analysis, so I'm not sure. I think this will simply be tcp.analysis.retransmission if Ethernet fails to deliver the frame to TCP within time. See this [page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvTCPAnalysis.html). This assumes apt uses TCP (e.g. by communicating with HTTPS or FTP, [which seems likely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146108/how-to-use-https-with-apt-get/146117#146117)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself, since no one else can really answer without visiting. :D

Thanks for the comments to my question.

Initially, I took the wrong approach to this problem. I am a software developer, so naturally I suspected software errors.

But after replacing the cables one by one, I found the culprit. It was a 1 meter pre-manufactured cat5e cable that came with the router. There were no mechanical damage and the cable has been fine for more than two years.

There is probably some sort of wisdom to gain from this, but right now I'm just happy that the problem is solved.